# Merging App + Profile Page With Same Name Post Feb 2012

Tags: facebook, merge

I am admin of two pages. One of them is an app page and the other is our brand page.

The app page name is Talkwheel Community (the name given to us by Facebook since our app name is Talkwheel) and the brand page is Talkwheel with more fans. I want to merge them into the app page and am an admin of both. How do I do this? I do not see the Merge Page link in the Edit Page>Update Info>Resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible - you could possibly merge the existing page onto the app's community page via the page merge process, but i'm not 100% sure how that works - it'd be off topic for this site, you'd need to check Facebook's Help Centre: https://www.facebook.com/help